# How to fix Future<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Future<Void>?

Tags: java, generics, concurrency

I need to create list of futures to control when all tasks (in JavaFX) are completed. So I have the following code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

...
ExecutorService actionExecutor = ...;
List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        ....
        return null;
    }
};
Future<Void> future = actionExecutor.submit(task); //LINE X
futures.add(future);
```

At `LINE X` I get `Future<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Future<Void>`. What is my mistake?

Comment: Given that they're `Future<Void>`s, you can't be especially interested in the result. Why not just use `Future<?>`?

Comment: @Andy Turner Thank you for your comment. Of course I can. But I want to understand what I do wrong and not to make this mistake in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) is a `Runnable`, so when you pass it to [`ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-), a `Future<?>` is returned.

If you want `ExecutorService.submit` to return a `Future<Void>`, you have to submit a `Callable<Void>`; or supply the return value via `actionExecutor.submit(task, null)`.

Alternatively, change to using `Future<?>` as the variable type/list element type.